# React I can't change my input field's value if it has a value and onChange

Tags: reactjs

I have a CRUD application, in my component's state I save the ***name*** of the user. Now the problem is: I have an input field for name in my form and when the user clicks on ***update*** user from the list, the selected user's name will appear on the input field and then I'm unable to change the name because the input field won't let me. I delete a letter and it reappears automatically, how can I fix this?

In my component's render method:

```
 <div className="col-sm-9">
      <div className="form-check">
          <input name="user_name" ref="user_name" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="user_name"
                 value={this.state.user_name} onChange={this.onChange} />          
      </div>
  </div>
```

Outside my render method:

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

Comment: not sure I understand the problem?

Comment: The problem is not in the part of the component you posted, but somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Have you bind your `onChange` method(i suppose that is the issue, that your state is not getting updated). If not, then :
try changing to this :

```
onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

**Or** to this :

```
<div className="col-sm-9">
      <div className="form-check">
          <input name="user_name" ref="user_name" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="user_name"
                 value={this.state.user_name} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />          
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: or you can also bind in the constructor `this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);`

Comment: Yes. since constructor code is not mentioned. So i didn't suggest that option.